# Getting Jenkins BUILD environment variables from within a python script

Tags: python, jenkins

Jenkins version: 2.74

As part of my build step I am running a python script and was hoping to access Jenkins build variables like BUILD_ID, BUILD_NUMBER, BUILD_URL etc.

I did the following in my script just to try it out but did not see any of the keys above listed:

```
import os

print os.environ
```

Output:

```
{
    'USERNAME': 'root',
    'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8',
    'TERM': 'xterm-256color',
    'SHELL': '/bin/bash',
    'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000',
    'SUDO_COMMAND': '/bin/su myuser -c python jenkinstest.py',
    'SHLVL': '1',
    'HOME': '/usr/home1/myuser',
    'SUDO_UID': '117',
    'SUDO_GID': '125',
    'PWD': '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/script-test',
    'LOGNAME': 'myuser',
    'USER': 'myuser',
    'PATH': '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games',
    'MAIL': '/var/mail/myuser',
    'SUDO_USER': 'jenkins',
    'XDG_SESSION_ID': '6',
    '_': '/usr/bin/python'
}
```

Why so?

And how can I access the keys I mentioned above from within the python script (without using the Jenkins python/json API) ?

Comment: when using `sudo` You must pay attention to the option `--preserve-env`, without it env variables are lost when switching user context.

Comment: @Take_Care_ If you put this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `sudo` You must pay attention to the option `--preserve-env`, without it env variables are lost when switching user context.